# ERC20 Interface

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20, interfaces

When you make a token, must you have an ERC20 Interface (such as the one below)? What is the purpose of it?

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

/// @notice ERC20 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20 with optional symbol, name and decimals

interface ERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);

    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}
```

I was wondering, instead of making a function for the totalSupply, couldn't I just make `uint256 totalSupply;`, `uint256 public totalSupply;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you make a token, must you have an ERC20 interface?

No, you must **implement** the ERC20 interface.

Declaring those functions in an `interface` is just a good programming practice, as it allows you to use that interface instead of the actual contract elsewhere in your code.

> Instead of `function totalSupply`, couldn't I just use `uint256 public totalSupply`?

Of course you can, that's what '**implementing the interface**' means.

No one forces you to explicitly implement `function totalSupply`, but just so you know, when you declare `uint256 public totalSupply`, you implicitly implement the same function (i.e., the compiler auto-generates it for you). So technically speaking, there is no difference.

The reason why some (for example, Open-Zeppelin), declare `uint256 private totalSupply` and then implement `function totalSupply` explicitly is, yet again, for good programming practice.

For example, when you declare `uint256 public totalSupply`, any contract which inherits from your contract can change this variable internally, which may well be undesirable. Of course, if you don't have such contract in the system then it shouldn't be a problem, but a good programming practice also means that you plan ahead and do it "the right way" even if there is no "imminent threat".

Comment: So you do need to have it?

Comment: @Lucus: Did you read the answer? Specifically the very top line, right below the line which quotes your question???

Comment: Yes I did. I asked: "When you make a token, must you have an ERC20 interface?", you replied "No, you must implement the ERC20 interface.".

Comment: @Lucus: I wrote you must implement the interface, but you don't need to declare it (as shown in your question). Do you not understand the difference between *declare* and *implement*?

Comment: No, I do not. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @Lucus: Declaration is what you posted in your question - a set of empty (non-implemented) functions, with only their prototypes (function name, input parameter types and output parameter types) being declared.

Comment: Implementation also includes the actual code of each function.